# get_avatar_url(get_avatar()) always return default 96 size?

Tags: wordpress

Not sure why I am not getting the size which I am passing i.e 260. I know the limit is 512 but still I am getting 96 sized avatar instead of 260 which is the case here.

My code:

```
<?php $avatar_url = get_avatar_url(get_avatar( $curauth->ID, 260 )); ?>
<div class="author-thumbnail" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $avatar_url; ?>');"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you only need `get_avatar_url` and `$curauth->ID`. It looks like you're calling the avatar twice by using `get_avatar` inside the function. The array for the size arg is right.

```
<?php $avatar_url = get_avatar_url($curauth->ID, array("size"=>260)); ?>
<div class="author-thumbnail" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $avatar_url; ?>');"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Got it! I had to give array arguments to get_avatar_url() while I was giving it to get_avatar().

```
<?php $avatar_url = get_avatar_url(get_avatar( $curauth->ID, 100 ), array("size"=>260)); ?>
<div class="author-thumbnail" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $avatar_url; ?>');"></div>
```