# How to get the URL of the get_avatar_url function in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, get, avatar

Would you be able to help me with my problem?

What I'm trying to do is get the exact URL of the get_avatar_url() function in WordPress. Then use the URL as the background-image url.

Here's how my code looked like.

```
<?php $avatar_url = get_avatar_url(get_avatar($author->ID, 150), array("size"=>260)); ?>
<div class="col-xs-5 nopadding author-picture" style="background: url('<?php echo $avatar_url; ?>')">
    <a class="author-block " href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url($author->ID); ?>">
          <figure class="author-picture">
                 <?php echo get_avatar($author->ID, 150); ?>
          </figure>
    </a>
</div>
```

However, on the page it is returning like this:
[image]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35314867/get-avatar-urlget-avatar-always-return-default-96-size

Answer (score 1):

The usage of `get_avatar_url` is `get_avatar_url( mixed $id_or_email, array $args = null )`. Why are you passing `get_avatar` to this function.

You can use this directly like this:

```
get_avatar_url($author->ID, array("size"=>260 ));
```

Comment: Hi Amit, thanks for the quick response. I've been actually scouring google for possible solution to my problem prior to me posting the question. That code you see was the last one I tried from the suggestion I saw online.

I tried your answer as well but it still didn't return the actual URL of the image.

Or, maybe I was using the wrong term in my question. My goal is to get the value of the "src" attribute of the get_avatar function so I can use it on the background-image url.

Comment: But  `get_avatar_url` is supposed to return the url that `get_avatar` uses to create the `src` in the `img` element it creates. so using that function should suffice.

Comment: Hi Amit, unfortunately this is the return that I get. 
background: url(https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/e57e294e57b764ab4f6ffc3ee2d07466?s=260&d=mm&r=g

Comment: The get_avatar_url  function seems to be returning the URL. Whats not working for you? Is it that the URL returned is that of default gravatar? If it is then may be that particular user doesnt have gravatar account. if the issue is that the URL of gravatar sent is not being shown in your pages, then may be its baecause your site is being served with HTTP and the gravatar URL is on HTTPs

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
<?php $avatar_url = get_avatar_url(get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), array('size' => 450)); ?>

<div class="col-xs-5 nopadding author-picture" style="background: url('<?php echo esc_url( $avatar_url ); ?>')">
```

Comment: Hi Mo'men, unfortunately it's still returning the same thing.
This is what it returns:
https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/d8ce87606c540f1d8bf07bcff50e5516?s=450&d=mm&r=g

Comment: Put this function in your functions.php |

 function get_avatar_url($get_avatar){
    preg_match("/src='(.*?)'/i", $get_avatar, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}

Comment: Hi Mo'men, I added the script on in the functions.php file as per your suggestion but it unfortunately rendered the page empty. As in it did not load the whole HTML at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think the background URL rule must contain a recognizable image extension (jpg, jpeg, gif, png).

To achieve this, you can:

first, get the whole html of the avatar for the specified user ID...

... then extract the url containing the image extension from it, using regex...

and finally use it in your code as follows.

```
$imageHtml = get_avatar($author->ID, 150); 

$imageUrlWithType = [];

preg_match('#\bhttps?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $imageHtml, $imageUrlWithType);

<div class="col-xs-5 nopadding author-picture" style="background: url('<?php echo $imageUrlWithType[0]; ?>')">
    <a class="author-block " href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url($author->ID); ?>">
          <figure class="author-picture">
                 <?php echo get_avatar($author->ID, 150); ?>
          </figure>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
get_avatar_url( $current_user->ID );
```

Comment: Did you read the question? Asker wants to know where this function itself can be found, not just how to call it (I think they could figure this out on their own).